# Post Request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token keeps failing in Code, Works on Postman

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to get access token through a post request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token, but it keeps giving me an error:

> "An error occurred while sending the request."

It works fine through Postman and Fiddler with same content. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong in the code?

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(request.AbsoluteUrl);
string googleCode = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("code");

var googleClientId = "435335443.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var uri = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
var googleClientSecret = "Test123";
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
var data = new GoogleAccessToken
           {
              clientId = googleClientId,
              clientSecret = googleClientSecret,
              grant_type = "authorization_code",
              redirect_uri = "http://localhost:53419/GoogleOAuth", //Same as one I used to get the code
              code = googleCode
          };

var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var rawResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

> Error - "An error occurred while sending the request."

Json request

```json
{"code":"657856987608768-asfdsacsdcsd","client_Id":"435335443.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"Test123","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:53419/GoogleOAuth","grant_type":"authorization_code"}
```

My Postman Request works fine

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json


{
"code":"657856987608768-asfdsacsdcsd",
"client_id":"435335443.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"client_secret":"Test123",
"redirect_uri":"http://localhost:53419/GoogleOAuth",
"grant_type":"authorization_code"
}
```

Comment: Inspect your `jsonRequest`. Does it look exactly like the one in Postman?

Comment: @Dunning-Kruger Yeah, it looks exactly the same

Comment: Could you paste it in for me to take a look?

Comment: @Dunning-Kruger Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

```
"client_Id"
```

from your request is not the same as

```
"client_id"
```

in Postman call. Try to change your request in Postman, so you can understand what is wrong with your code request.

You can catch something like this in your response:

```
{
   "error": "invalid_request",
   "error_description": "Could not determine client ID from request."
}
```